# Broken DAG needs a fix. Tried reinstalling and updating the packages

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

DAG is broken and says needs version 10 or above for libpq, I have version 12.

I am trying to run a DAG on my local system.

I have installed all the dependency packages and I still keep getting this error message. I have tried re installing and updating the packages.

Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/jobs/etl/oe/doc.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fast/db.py", line 347, in db
return psycopg2.connect(dbname=dbname, host=host, user=user, password=password)
File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/**init**.py", line 122, in connect
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above

pip install --upgrade psycopg2
brew install psycopg2

Nothing seem to fix this issue. Can someone help me with this?